# How to make this query faster

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT D.A1, D.A2, D.A3  from D, l1
     ,l2 where
     l1.Z = "90001"and substring(D.A1,1,5) = substring(l2.A1,1,5) and substring(D.A2,1,5) = substring(l2.A2,1,5)
    AND 3959 * (PI()/180) * SQRT(
        POW( (l2.A2-l1.A2)*COS((PI()/180)*(l2.A1+l2.A1)/2), 2 ) + 
         POW( l2.A1-l1.A1, 2 ) ) <= 10');
```

This is taking forever to run. I am not sure how to make this faster.

Comment: Why do you have `');` on the end of your query? Copy+paste error, perhaps?

Comment: I am using PHP prepare statement

Comment: If I remove table D an select only attributes from either l1 or l2 it works really fast

Answer (score 0):

What indexes do you have? Have you got an index on `l1.Z`? If not, this would be an obvious way to start.

You could also store the results of expressions like `substring(l2.A1,1,5)` in the table itself. This would allow you to index the results of the expressions, meaning that your join will be faster.

It also looks like you are trying to find things that are "nearby" in space. If so, have a look at MySQLs [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html).

Comment: I forgot to add Z to table D thats why I am using A1 and A2 to to compare D to L2

Comment: The problem is that I have 50 millions rows and very low disk space. I can't add that to the table.

Comment: @cool_cs: Oh please be serious! Just buy a larger hard disk! Even if you somehow manage to solve this problem without creating any new columns or indexes, you are going to run into other problems in the near future where you will have no choice other than to upgrade your hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

The design of your database looks weird to me and I'm pretty sure MySQL can't use INDEX with theses conditions

```
substring(D.A1,1,5) = substring(l2.A1,1,5) and substring(D.A2,1,5) = substring(l2.A2,1,5)
```

Henceforth the bad performance :/

Answer (score 0):

You should start by rewriting the query with joins, and see if that helps anything:

```
select D.A1, D.A2, D.A3
from D
inner join l2 on substring(D.A1,1,5) = substring(l2.A1,1,5) and substring(D.A2,1,5) = substring(l2.A2,1,5)
inner join l1 on 3959 * (PI()/180) * SQRT( POW( (l2.A2-l1.A2)*COS((PI()/180)*(l2.A1+l2.A1)/2), 2 ) + POW( l2.A1-l1.A1, 2 ) ) <= 10
where l1.Z = "90001"
```

Answer (score 0):

coll_cs,you can try this

```
select D1.A1, D1.A2, D1.A3
     from 
     ( 
        SELECT substring(D.A1,1,5) AS A1,
                substring(D.A2,1,5) AS A2,
                D.D3 AS D3
        from D
     ) as D1
     ,
     (
        select 
        substring(l2.A1,1,5) AS A1,
        substring(l2.A2,1,5) AS A2
        l1,l2
        where l1.Z = "90001"
        and
        3959 * 
        (PI()/180) * 
        SQRT(
        POW( (l2.A2-l1.A2)*COS((PI()/180)*(l2.A1+l2.A1)/2), 2 ) + 
        POW( l2.A1-l1.A1, 2 ) 
        ) <= 10
     ) as L
     where D1 = L.A1
     and   D1 = L.A2
```

I don't have enough information about the table, such is field type, number of rows, keys and indexes

UPDATED FORMATTING